# Clamp X position of object in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop, ngui

Here is my code in unity 3d

```
moveDirection = Vector3.forward + new Vector3(Input.acceleration.x * 0.3f, 0, 0);   

// transform.position.x = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, -2.0f, 2.0f);

transform.Translate(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime *9);
```

A object moving forward. I want to clamp its x position.

```
transform.position.x = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, -2.0f, 2.0f);
```

which gives me

error CS1612: Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.Transform.position'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable

How can i clamp my object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity is pretty stupid in this regard, so a bit of a workaround is required. Try this:

```
Vector3 tmpPos = transform.position;
tmpPos.x = Mathf.Clamp(tmpPos.x, -2.0f, 2.0f);
transform.position = tmpPos;
```

Comment: Gets error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `float' to `UnityEngine.Vector3

Comment: @Sona oups, forgot the .x I edited my answer with the fix, so it should be ok now

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the x value directly, here's a work-around:

```
transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, -2.0f, 2.0f), transform.position.y, transform.position.z)
```